# $\left [\mathbb{Z}\left [i\right ]/\left (a\right ):K\right ]$, $a$ irreducible, $K$ prime field

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

If I have an irreducible element $a\in \mathbb{Z}\left [i\right ]$ and $K$ is the prime field of $\mathbb{Z}\left [i\right ]/\left (a\right )$, how do I find $\left [\mathbb{Z}\left [i\right ]/\left (a\right ):K\right ]$?

I tried supposing $a\in \mathbb{Z}$, therefore $a$ is a prime number and $a\equiv 3\pmod 4$. Since $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(a)\cong \mathbb{Z}/a\mathbb{Z}[i]/(a)$ and $K=\mathbb{F}_a$ we have that $[\mathbb{Z}[i]/(a):K]=2$ because $X^2+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_a[X]$.

I do not know how to solve the general case.

Comment: The other two cases are 1) the prime field = $\mathbb F_2$, and 2) the prime field is  $\mathbb F_p$, with $p\equiv 1 \pmod 4$. For both cases, $-1$ is  a square in $\mathbb F_p$, so... Are you OK at this point?

Comment: I could follow you.

Comment: So can you do the question?

Comment: If $-1$ is a square in $\mathbb{F}_p$ then the degree would be $1$ because $x^2+1$ would be reducible... Is that ok?

Comment: That's right. Explicitly, $i \equiv n \pmod a$ (in your notation), for some rational integer $n$.

Comment: But I still do not understand why $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(a)\cong \mathbb{F}_p[i]$ in this last case.

Comment: No $\mathbb Z[i]/(a) \cong \mathbb F_p$. For instance, ${\mathbb Z[}i]/(1-i) \simeq \mathbb F_2$. Likewise $\mathbb Z[i]/(2+i) \simeq \mathbb F_5$.

Comment: And how do you define the isomorphism? (excuse me for my ignorance, it is my first approach to the topic)

Comment: Oh, I see... on the one hand (for the cases with prime field $\mathbb F_p$ with $p\not\equiv -1 \pmod 4$), one can choose not to define the iso explicitly, as one has that $\mathbb Z[i]/a$ is a field extension of degree $1$ over the prime field, so one is just 'done'.  But to define the iso... some examples: for $a = 1-i $, $i\mapsto 1\in \mathbb F_2$ works (look previous comment above). For $a= 2+i$, take $i\mapsto -2 \in \mathbb F_5$.  For $a = 3-2i$, take $i\mapsto 8 \in \mathbb F_{13}$.  (cont)

Comment: (cont) One chooses, for image of $i$ in the residue field $\mathbb F_p$, the root of $-1$ (the one of the two choices, except for $p=2$) that kills $a$ - which has to be the case, as $(a)$ is  the kernel. Get it?

Comment: Namely, if $a = m+ni$, ($m$ and $n$ rational integers) we need to choose rational integer $k$, where $k^2 \equiv  -1 \pmod p$, such that $p | (m+n\cdot k)$.

Comment: Thank you very much! If $a=b+di$ then $p\mid b^2+d^2$, so we can choose $-\frac{b}{d}$ (which is a root of $-1$) as the image of $i$, and then the kernel is $(a)$.

Comment: Exactly right - when I first saw your question, I wasn't sure what you weren't seeing, since you clearly understood the $p\equiv -1 \pmod 4$ case. But that's the way it goes in math, doesn't it... best wishes!